# Convert XPathNavigator to HtmlAgilityPack's HtmlNode

Tags: c#, xpath, .net-2.0, html-agility-pack, xpathnavigator

It is possible to convert `XPathNavigator` to `HtmlNode`? 
Here is the code:

```
public string ContentByName(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("name");

    XPathExpression expr = _CreateXPathExpression(String.Format("//meta[@name[Extensions:CaseInsensitiveComparison('{0}')]]", name));
    XPathNodeIterator it = _headNav.Select(expr);
    if (!it.MoveNext())
        return null;

    XPathNavigator node = it.Current;

    // How should I transform XPathNavigator node to HtmlNode here?

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'it.Current' in your example returns an instance of `HtmlNodeNavigator` which has a `CurrentNode` property which in turn returns the `HtmlNode`.

For example

```
HtmlNodeNavigator nodeNavigator = it.Current as HtmlNodeNavigator;
HtmlNode node = nodeNavigator.CurrentNode;
```

Comment: @christaylor is it possible to convert htmlnode to xmlnode or vice versa?